# How to calculate the volume of dry hydrogen in magnesium/ HCl reaction

Tags: gas-laws

I am not sure if the equivalents of $\ce{H2}$ in the equation 
$$\ce{Mg (s) + 2HCl (aq) -> MgCl2 (aq) + H2}$$
is that of dry or wet hydrogen.

If the $\ce{H2}$ refers to wet hydrogen in the equation, how should I find the volume of dry hydrogen given the pressure of wet and dry hydrogen and the volume of wet hydrogen?

Comment: The water is a liquid.  It exerts a vapor pressure.  Some of the pressure in the gas is not due to hydrogen, it is due to water vapor so it is called wet hydrogen.

Comment: Not a duplicate, plus the linked question does not have an answer.